# Запись "сравнений" в базу

Tags: mysql

Есть задача: сохранить сравнения автомобилей.
Делал таблицу:

```
id 
car_id_1
car_id_2
count - общее кол. по данному сравнению автомобилей
```

Так вот, если я например добавил Audi 3 vs BMW i3, то тогда я не могу достать тоже самое сравнение по BMW i3 vs Audi 3.

Пол дня ломал себе голову, так не нашел ответ, что бы одним запросом с использованием `LIMIT`.

Уверен, не верно сделал структуру для этого.

Comment: Покажите, что за полдня получилось. Добавте запрос прямо в вопрос.

Comment: а зачем limit, если вы ищете только одну запись `where (car_id_1=X and car_id_2=Y) or (car_id_2=X and car_id_1=Y)`

Comment: ответил ниже, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Измените структуру, сделайте 2 таблицы.

Первая - сравниваемые машины. (ID машины - ID сравнения)

Вторая - количество сравнений. (ID сравнения - количество)

Такая структура, кроме логичности и удобства, позволит сравнивать любое количество объектов (скажем, три машины сразу).

Comment: Вот такого плана я и думал, но может устал уже за день, но не поняд как мне потом доставать эти же сравнения. Более глубакая суть - достать машины которые в определенных "таксах" лежат. https://pastebin.com/j6aWJMtL

Comment: Слово "такса" в русском языке имеет 2 значения. И любое из них смотрится в твоей фразе ... ну скажем так - не по делу.

Comment: если уточнить, Таксономия (Wordpress - https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

Comment: Ну  со словом определились... осталось понять, что скрывается под получившейся фразой. И лучше, если Вы заранее подумайте о том, что только Вы знаете предметную область, задачу, и понимаете прикладываемый к ней слэнг.

Comment: Я помогу. Таксономия - это как категория, а термин таксономии как раздел этой категории. В данном запросе я уже знаю что мне надо достать электроавтомобили, это term_taxonomy_id.

Comment: ТО есть это некие значения из связанных таблиц.  Тогда не вижу причин для беспокойства - просто добавляем в источник данных запроса нужные таблицы, а также необходимые условия связывания и условия отбора.